# Does putting ARG at top of Dockerfile prevent layer re-use?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

If an ARG that is declared at the top of a Dockerfile gets changed, but its value is only used for a RUN command near the end of the Dockerfile, does Docker rebuild the whole image from scratch or is it able to re-use the intermediate image from right before the relevant RUN command?

To better utilize layering, should I place my ARG declarations at the top of the Dockerfile, or just before the section that uses them?

I guess part of my question is whether or not an ARG directive generates an intermediate layer.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In general, it is better to place `ARG` just before it is used rather than at the top of the file.

To be more precise, not all lines are cache invalidated after an `ARG` declaration. Only those that use `ARG` values and `RUN`s. The docker documentation provides details:

> **Impact on build caching**
>
> `ARG` variables are not persisted into the built image as `ENV` variables are. However, `ARG` variables do impact the build cache in similar ways. If a Dockerfile defines an ARG variable whose value is different from a previous build, then a “cache miss” occurs upon its first usage, not its definition. In particular, all `RUN` instructions following an `ARG` instruction use the `ARG` variable implicitly (as an environment variable), thus can cause a cache miss. All predefined `ARG` variables are exempt from caching unless there is a matching `ARG` statement in the Dockerfile.

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#impact-on-build-caching

You'll have to move your `ARG`s under the `RUN`s that would not need the argument in order to keep layer cache optimized.

For more info:

- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/18017
- https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/18161
- RUN explanation here: https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/21885

Comment: ENV command (ENV_X ${ENV_XVAR}) seems to never use cache. Even though the value is unchanged.

Comment: This appears to have changed in more recent docker versions (tested with 24.0.5) and is now based on the position of the `ARG` declaration, not its first usage.

Answer (score 40):

If you change the value of a build argument all of the layers after that ARG line will be invalidated. So I guess you should include it just before you use the ARG.

Just before you need it:

```
 docker build --build-arg TEST_ARG=test .
 Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
 Step 1 : FROM ubuntu
 ---> 104bec311bcd
 Step 2 : RUN echo "no arg used"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5c29cb363a27
 Step 3 : ARG TEST_ARG
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 73b6080f973b
 Step 4 : RUN echo $TEST_ARG
 ---> 0acd55c24441
 Successfully built 0acd55c24441
```

At the top:

```
docker build --build-arg TEST_ARG=test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1 : FROM ubuntu
 ---> 104bec311bcd
Step 2 : ARG TEST_ARG
---> Using cache
---> b611a1023fe3
Step 3 : RUN echo "no arg used"
---> Running in 63e0f803c6b2
no arg used
---> 592311ccad72
Removing intermediate container 63e0f803c6b2
Step 4 : RUN echo $TEST_ARG
---> Running in 1515aa8702f0
test
---> fc2d850fbbeb
Removing intermediate container 1515aa8702f0
Successfully built fc2d850fbbeb
```

In the first example two layers are used from the cache and in the second one only one layer (funnily enough, the ARG layer itself) is used from the cache.

Comment: This appears to be the correct answer as of docker 24.0.5.